# Is it possible to have more than one Exchange box serving the same domain?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, exchange

As the question states, is it possible to have more than one Exchange service serving the same domain for a single store? Is clustering required or is it like Active Directory (just promote and add to the domain).

This question has server standard in mind (not enterprise or data center where clustering is possible).

If this is possible, what steps should I take to make this happen?  The benefit I am looking for is replication and fault tolerance (take one of the two servers down, but still have service available).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes. For more details, you'll need to specify which version of Exchange you've got.

Comment: Ideal situation would be exchange 2010, But I get the feeling its going to be intermingeled with 2003 as well.

Comment: 2003 and 2010 can co-exist, but I think we'd need more details to understand what you really are trying to do. With 2010, DAG does depends on Windows clustering, so no Standard Edition, sorry. With 2007, CCR also depends on Windows clustering. SCR on 2007 did not depend on clustering.